# String Combination/Permutation

Tags: java, string, algorithm, combinations

I'm trying to write a program that, when given two strings, it 'juggles' a letter around to form synonyms. Here's a website that shows an example of it:

http://www.braingle.com/brainteasers/46611/letter-juggle.html

My task is to "write a program which — given a file containing pairs of synonyms 
and a second file containing a sequence of words from a dictionary — will produce as many pairs of words from the dictionary as possible that can be used to set the puzzle for each synonym pair."

These are the files - [dictionary.txt](https://docs.google.com/a/tcd.ie/file/d/0ByMP-XLaZiP4N1BCQmdHSGFpZGM/edit) and [synonyms.txt](https://docs.google.com/a/tcd.ie/file/d/0ByMP-XLaZiP4VTc4bWxFZG1ZWUk/edit).

When I juggle up a word, I check the dictionary to see if it's valid. So taking the words "boast" and "hip", when I juggle them up I can get "boat" and "ship" (which are synonyms).

Right now, I have taken two strings (nail and pin) and split them into a char array but I'm not sure how to juggle them to check if they are valid words.

I want to be able to add the letter "n" from "nail" to "pin" to give me "pinn", I want to 
then go through every combination of "pinn" and check if it's a valid word - if it is, I then check to see if "ail" can be a word, if not, then I move on to the next letter in "nail"
pinn - > pinn, pnin, pnni, pnin......

```
public class LetterJuggle {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try{
        // Open the file that is the first 
        // command line parameter
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Dictionary.txt"); //Dictionary.txt //Synonyms.txt
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        int size =0;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            size++;
        }

        String [] dictionary = new String [size];

        fstream = new FileInputStream("Dictionary.txt");
        in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        size = 0;
        //Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            // Print the content on the console
            dictionary[size] = strLine;
            size++; 
        }

        fstream = new FileInputStream("Synonyms.txt");
        in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            //System.out.println(strLine);
            String [] words = strLine.split("\\s+");
            for(int i =0; i < words.length; i++){
                //System.out.println(words[i]);
            }
            char[] ch_array_1 = words[0].toCharArray();
            char[] ch_array_2 = words[1].toCharArray();

            for(int i =0; i < ch_array_1.length; i++){
                System.out.print(ch_array_1[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            for(int i =0; i < ch_array_2.length; i++){
                System.out.print(ch_array_2[i] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        //Close the input stream
        in.close();
    }catch(Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }    


}
```

}

Comment: @PradeepSimha All I have so far is a char array of both strings. I'm just looking a good way to juggle the letters and check if they are valid. I'm not necessarily asking for code.

Comment: did you mean array rotation?

Comment: Please show your program here then we can help you easily

Comment: @PradeepSimha I dont know what an array rotation is. But it sounds like what I want to do. I think the right is Permutation.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily efficient, but it's an idea. Use some (2) loops and take one letter form first word and add it at all positions (from index 0 to after last letter index) and check if both are valid words (the word with the removed letter and the newly formed word).
(some pseudocode)

```
for (Letter l : word1)
{
    Word word1temp = extract_Letter_l_from_word(l,word1);
    check if word1temp and word2 are synonyms
    //else
    for (all letter indexes i of word2)
    {
         form word with letter L at position i and word2 form a synonim of word2
         // also maybe do this in the mirror for word2 and word1
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind but it just looked really long. But I can do it if there;s no other way. Thanks.

Comment: I am sure there may be a more efficient/smart way to solve this, but this was the first idea that came to mind

Answer (score 1):

Try this, permutation of array:[Permutation of Array](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/programs/combinations/Permute-java.html)

Posted code here, so that even link is outdated, you can refer here. I think this helps you

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Permute implements Iterator {

private final int size;
   private final Object [] elements;  // copy of original 0
   private final Object ar;           // array for output, 
   private final int [] permutation;  // perm of nums 1..si

private boolean next = true;

// int[], double[] array won't work :-(
   public Permute (Object [] e) {
      size = e.length;
      elements = new Object [size];    // not suitable for 
      System.arraycopy (e, 0, elements, 0, size);
      ar = Array.newInstance (e.getClass().getComponentType
      System.arraycopy (e, 0, ar, 0, size);
      permutation = new int [size+1];
      for (int i=0; i
         permutation [i]=i;
      }
   }

private void formNextPermutation () {
      for (int i=0; i
         // i+1 because perm[0] always = 0
         // perm[]-1 because the numbers 1..size are being 
         Array.set (ar, i, elements[permutation[i+1]-1]);
      }
   }

public boolean hasNext() {
      return next;
   }

public void remove() throws UnsupportedOperationExceptio
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }

private void swap (final int i, final int j) {
      final int x = permutation[i];
      permutation[i] = permutation [j];
      permutation[j] = x;
   }

// does not throw NoSuchElement; it wraps around!
   public Object next() throws NoSuchElementException {

```
  formNextPermutation ();  // copy original elements   

  int i = size-1;                                      
  while (permutation[i]>permutation[i+1]) i--;         

  if (i==0) {                                          
     next = false;                                     
     for (int j=0; j<size+1; j++) {                    
        permutation [j]=j;                             
     }                                                 
     return ar;                                        
  }                                                    

  int j = size;                                        

  while (permutation[i]>permutation[j]) j--;           
  swap (i,j);                                          
  int r = size;                                        
  int s = i+1;                                         
  while (r>s) { swap(r,s); r--; s++; }                 

  return ar;
```

}

```
 public String toString () {                             
  final int n = Array.getLength(ar);                   
  final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer ("[");      
  for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {                            
     sb.append (Array.get(ar,j).toString());           
     if (j<n-1) sb.append (",");                       
  }                                                    
  sb.append("]");                                      
  return new String (sb);
```

}

public static void main (String [] args) {
      for (Iterator i = new Permute(args); i.hasNext(); ) {
         final String [] a = (String []) i.next();
         System.out.println (i);
      }
   }
}

Comment: Please excuse me for code formatting